# Google Maps Geolocation API on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, leaflet, google-geolocation

I'm developing an Android App with Phonegap. Everything works fine except the geolocation function in rural areas. When tested, the device being offline couldn't find a location using the standard browser's geolocation API. Without a sim card there was no cell-tower triangulation possible, neither were any wifi spots available so the only way to locate the device was GPS only (I guess). But after waiting for 15 minutes i gave up.

I then switched to Google Maps and I was stunned how fast my device was located. I had made sure that my location cache was empty. I don't understand how Google was able to locate me under the given circumstances that quickly. I've read that a raw GPS location takes 10 minutes easily. I got the same result when I located myself back at home with my Iphone in airplane mode. Impressive!

Now I want to switch from Cordova Geolocation to Google Geolocation API, but can't find any recources to do so in my Phonegap environment. I'm using Leaflet and want the user to click on a button to locate oneself quickly and accurately on a mobile device. Is there a way to just integrate the Geolocation API (without google maps API) as JS and then call a function locateMeNow() ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to make use of the Android native API, using the [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) plugin.

Try it out first with the ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER mode, it's the fastest to get locations:

```
backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
    locationProvider: backgroundGeolocation.provider.ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
    desiredAccuracy: 1,
    stationaryRadius: 1,
    interval: 1 
}); 
backgroundGeolocation.start(startOkCb, startErrorCb);
```

The ANDROID_DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER mode takes around 20s to send the first location, because it precomputes the first gathered locations. Play with both modes, as well as with the rest of the conf options and adjust it to your needs.